# Clear crystal reports temp files

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Crystal reports temp files, delete the code for the close button in c# form. 
How do I clear the report cache? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link really helped me.Try it

http://www.pedautreppe.com/post/Crystal-Reports-generates-temporary-files.aspx

```
    private void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        CloseReports(cr); 
        cr.Dispose(); 
        CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose(); 
        CrystalReportViewer1 = null; 

    } 


    private void CloseReports(ReportDocument reportDocument) 
    { 
        Sections sections = reportDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections; 
        foreach (Section section in sections) 
        { 
            ReportObjects reportObjects = section.ReportObjects; 
            foreach (ReportObject reportObject in reportObjects) 
            { 
                if (reportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject) 
                { 
                    SubreportObject subreportObject = (SubreportObject)reportObject; 
                    ReportDocument subReportDocument = subreportObject.OpenSubreport(subreportObject.SubreportName); 
                    subReportDocument.Close(); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        reportDocument.Close(); 
    }
```

Globally open the report and globally close it inside the page.It will help